# 'What about the reverse' is correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct? e.g for a journal paper's title:

> Unemployment affects stress, what about the reverse?

Comment: I'm sure that it's fine as two sentences (*Unemployment affects stress. What about the reverse?*). I also think that it's fine in informal speech (*Unemployment affects stress - what about the reverse?*). I'm inclined to believe that, with some punctuation tricks, it might be fine as a title (*Unemployment Affects Stress – What about the Reverse?*).

Comment: @DamkerngT. thanks, your comment is really a good **ANSWER**. It would be better if you have posted it as one.

Comment: If you add since it would be fine: Since Unemployment affects stress, what about the reverse ?

Comment: A journal title might be more along the lines of: *Investigating the Correlation Between Unemployment and Stress as Both Cause and Effect.*  or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that it's fine as two sentences,

> Unemployment affects stress. What about the reverse?

I also think that it's fine in informal speech (I often see similar sentences in transcriptions),

> Unemployment affects stress – what about the reverse?

I'm inclined to believe that, with some punctuation tricks, it might be fine as a title (I would use it myself),

> **Unemployment Affects Stress – What about the Reverse?**

Answer (score -1):

I think the topic has its own format(structure).

it can be used in this way ."unemployment affects Stress ?"

Grammatically may be true or false, but here mentioned for a journal title .

But grammatically I think It is better to use "What about the reverse of it ".